# Java Phone/Item Picker

Tags: java

I'm creating a project in which users input the basic specifications of a phone and the program will compare this data to phones on the market now and return results of phones they would likely be happiest with.

I've currently only been able to get to a point in which users input this data, and as someone who's only been programming for a month, I have no clue as to how to compare this data to previously determined data, can someone help me finish this out?

```
import cs1.Keyboard;

public class CoolProject {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        double num_Memory, num_Screen, num_ProcessorSpeed, num_ProcessorCores, num_Battery, num_Camera, num_PPI;

        System.out.println("The most noticeable part of a phone is its' screen size. \nEnter the minimum screen size you'd like your phone to have: ");

        num_Screen = Keyboard.readInt();

        System.out.println("Fantastic! Most phones today have a 720p, 1080p, or 2K screen. \nWhat's the minimum screen resolution you'd like to have: ");

        num_PPI = Keyboard.readInt();

        System.out.println"(Nice! Now you're going to want to pick a battery to help power that display! What's the smallest battery you'd like to have: ");

        num_Battery = Keyboard.readInt();

        System.out.println("Great! So to run that powerhouse, you'll need a beast of a processor. How many cores do you want in your CPU: ");

        num_ProcessorCores = Keyboard.readInt();

        System.out.println("How fast do you want it to be? Keep in mind most phones run between 1 and 2.5ghz: ");

        num_ProcessorSpeed = Keyboard.readInt();

        System.out.println("Perfect! Last but not least, how many megapixels do you want in your phone? Remember most phones have between 4 and 21 Megapixels: ");

        num_Camera = Keyboard.readInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `if` statements?

Comment: Let's see.  You defined a group of double fields, then used a readInt method to read the numbers.

Comment: Sidenote: The naming convention in Java is camelCase, with no underscores. `numCamera` rather than `num_Camera`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a group of fields that you want to consider as one object.  Let's call these fields "phone specifications".

So, you create a class to store these fields and their values.  Let's call the class PhoneSpecification.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class PhoneSpecification {

    private double num_Memory, num_Screen, num_ProcessorSpeed,
            num_ProcessorCores, num_Battery, num_Camera, num_PPI;

    private String name;
    private String manufacturer;

    public double getNum_Memory() {
        return num_Memory;
    }

    public void setNum_Memory(double num_Memory) {
        this.num_Memory = num_Memory;
    }

    public double getNum_Screen() {
        return num_Screen;
    }

    public void setNum_Screen(double num_Screen) {
        this.num_Screen = num_Screen;
    }

    public double getNum_ProcessorSpeed() {
        return num_ProcessorSpeed;
    }

    public void setNum_ProcessorSpeed(double num_ProcessorSpeed) {
        this.num_ProcessorSpeed = num_ProcessorSpeed;
    }

    public double getNum_ProcessorCores() {
        return num_ProcessorCores;
    }

    public void setNum_ProcessorCores(double num_ProcessorCores) {
        this.num_ProcessorCores = num_ProcessorCores;
    }

    public double getNum_Battery() {
        return num_Battery;
    }

    public void setNum_Battery(double num_Battery) {
        this.num_Battery = num_Battery;
    }

    public double getNum_Camera() {
        return num_Camera;
    }

    public void setNum_Camera(double num_Camera) {
        this.num_Camera = num_Camera;
    }

    public double getNum_PPI() {
        return num_PPI;
    }

    public void setNum_PPI(double num_PPI) {
        this.num_PPI = num_PPI;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

}
```

You would create an instance of this class for each phone you want to use in the comparison.  You would create one instance of this class with the values received from the user.

Then, you compare the user phone specifications with the specifications you already created for the various phones.